# how to get heatmap based on clustering?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I am a attempting to get a unsupervised clustering where I am hoping to visualise my data in a meaningful and elegant way. I am new to clustering. Yet, not sure if I can visualise comorbidities and symptoms into clusters?

This is done in R.

Here is what I tried with no success:

```
 library(pheatmap)
 pheatmap(t(data), cutree_cols = 3)
```

and sample of data right bellow:

```
structure(list(Comorbidities = structure(1:9, .Label = c("asthma", 
"diabetes_type_one", "diabetes_type_two", "heart_disease", "hypertension", 
"kidney_disease", "liver_disease", "lung_condition", "obesity"
), class = "factor"), chills = c(26L, 22L, 23L, 43L, 22L, 15L, 
43L, 24L, 20L), cough = c(58L, 57L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 62L, 
58L, 59L), diarrhoea = c(21L, 14L, 16L, 25L, 19L, 21L, 25L, 19L, 
22L), fatigue = c(59L, 51L, 53L, 62L, 54L, 49L, 62L, 56L, 54L
), headache = c(44L, 30L, 34L, 44L, 39L, 33L, 48L, 43L, 42L), 
    loss_smell_taste = c(21L, 21L, 19L, 25L, 19L, 23L, 28L, 20L, 
    19L), muscle_ache = c(47L, 44L, 43L, 60L, 46L, 43L, 56L, 
    45L, 46L), nasal_congestion = c(34L, 25L, 32L, 36L, 33L, 
    33L, 46L, 38L, 34L), nausea_vomiting = c(11L, 10L, 9L, 18L, 
    7L, 12L, 28L, 13L, 9L), shortness_breath = c(61L, 36L, 32L, 
    53L, 35L, 50L, 44L, 50L, 37L), sore_throat = c(46L, 36L, 
    39L, 51L, 49L, 50L, 57L, 45L, 49L), sputum = c(47L, 34L, 
    41L, 50L, 39L, 41L, 47L, 46L, 43L), temperature = c(20L, 
    31L, 31L, 32L, 23L, 18L, 38L, 23L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), groups = structure(list(Comorbidities = structure(1:9, .Label = c("asthma", 
"diabetes_type_one", "diabetes_type_two", "heart_disease", "hypertension", 
"kidney_disease", "liver_disease", "lung_condition", "obesity"
), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `pheatmap(t(data[-1]), cutree_cols = 3)`

Comment: yet, my issues is that I want to see the comorbidities clustered with symptoms? Is this possible?

Comment: do `rownames(data) <- data$Comorbidities` first

Comment: @ Rawr - it did work nicely, How about you put this as a answer?